# JQuery. each() не сохраняет данные на форме

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я не знаю JQuery но пытаюсь его понять и научится. Я делаю веб-форму для себя . У меня есть свое Spring Boot приложение которое отдает json значения с базы MySql . 
В этом куске кода я пытаюсь получить запросом ajax этот json(приблизительно такой [{songName: "song1",songName: "song2",songName: "song3",}]) и разместить его на странице вызовом цикла each () .Если глянуть в дебаггер в хроме то все отрисовывается После того как я получаю последнее значение страница как будто перезагружается и данные не записываются. Скажите где я ошибся?

Дебаггер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После окончания цикла 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код

```js
function getSongsListArtists() {
    var artist = document.getElementById("artist1").textContent;
    var artistUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/songs/' + artist;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: artistUrl,
      async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: songReturn
    });
}

function songReturn(json) {
    $("#content").html("<span style='color: blue;font-size: 17px'>Песни артиста: </span>" +
                "<pre id='listSong'></pre>");
    $.each(json, function (idx, topic) {
    var song=topic.songName;
    jQuery("#listSong").append("<a id='songId" + idx +"' href=''>"+song+"</a>"+"</br>");
    });
}
```

Comment: А как вызываете метод getSongsListArtists()?

Comment: @Kosmos  $("#content").html("<pre>" +"<p><span style='color: blue;font-size: 17px'>Aртист: </span>"
            +"<a id='artist1' href='' onclick='getSongsListArtists()'>"+data.artistName+"</a>"+"</p>" + "</pre>");
    });

Comment: @Kosmos да с ним все правильно. Я описал выше что все возвращается. просто по окончанию цикла все то что было записано стирается ....

Comment: @Kosmos Спасибо что посмотрели. Буду надеяться что кто нибудь еще ответит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично. Вы пишете

> ```
> <a id='artist1' href='' onclick='getSongsListArtists()'>"+data.artistName+"</a>
> ```

т.е. при клике на ссылку вначале произойдет вызов функции `getSongsListArtists()` а потом произойдет переход по ссылке `href=''`, т.е. произойдет перезагрузка страницы.

Решения два:

1. Либо добавьте в функцию `getSongsListArtists` последней строкой `return false`

   ```
   function getSongsListArtists() {
       var artist = document.getElementById("artist1").textContent;
       var artistUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/songs/' + artist;
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: artistUrl,
           async: false,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: songReturn
       });
       return false;
   }
   ```

   что скажет браузеру отменить переход по ссылке.
2. Либо перейдите на саму эту функцию

   ```
   <a id='artist1' href='javascript:getSongsListArtists()'>"+data.artistName+"</a>
   ```

Comment: Я очень благодарен за попытку и Ваши аргументы весьма обоснованы и правильны. Я не заметил такой мелочи . Но это к сожалению тоже не сработало( спасибо

Comment: Простите,я невнимательно сейчас сделал.Все сработало.Спасибо огромное)